# cassandra - Saved cluster name Test Cluster != configured name

Tags: cassandra

How am I supposed to bot a new Cassandra node when I get this error?

```
INFO [SSTableBatchOpen:1] 2014-02-25 01:51:17,132 SSTableReader.java (line 223) Opening /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-jb-5 (5725 bytes)
ERROR [main] 2014-02-25 01:51:17,377 CassandraDaemon.java (line 237) Fatal exception during initialization
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Saved cluster name Test Cluster != configured name thisisstupid
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.SystemKeyspace.checkHealth(SystemKeyspace.java:542)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:233)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:462)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:552)
```

Name of cluster in the cassandra.yaml file is:

```
cluster_name: 'thisisstupid'
```

How do I resolve?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can rename the cluster without deleting data by updating it's name in the system.local table (but you have to do this **for each node**...)

```
cqlsh> UPDATE system.local SET cluster_name = 'test' where key='local';
# flush the sstables to persist the update.
bash $ ./nodetool flush
```

Finally you need to rename the cluster to the new name in cassandra.yaml (again **on each node**)

Comment: what dir's are those?

Comment: Check for the `data_file_directories`, `commitlog_directory` (and in 2.1 flush_directory) settings in `cassandra.yaml`

Comment: dirs are in /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog
  /var/lib/cassandra/data  so....delete or flush contents of the dirs?

Comment: @Tampa del them, but this will delete all your data aswell. You are basically completely wiping the cluster.

Comment: nice @Tampa, deleting those is the right move in the case you're just setting up a new node and forgot to change the name in the config :)

Comment: I believe `bash $ ./nodetool flush` should be `bash $ ./nodetool flush system`. For details, see [here](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/205289825-Change-Cluster-Name-)

Comment: If Cassandra couldn't be started due to the stated error, then we obviously can't use the cqlsh approach. We would then need to delete the files at system keyspace and restart the service.

Comment: @user2275460 Great, but how do you do that without data loss? Also the exception only appears in the new node being added, the others can start up, thus that is where the cql update needs to occur. You propagate the change to all your nodes, then start the new node and the exception will be resolved.

Comment: @user2275460 I was unable to start the cluster due to this issue. I've deleted the files at /var/lib/cassandra/data/system. Still see the issue. Is there any work around?

Answer (score 32):

The above commands with `UPDATE SET cluster_name` does not work for me. I found the working is to follow the instructions from  [the DataStax documentation on **Initializing a multiple node cluster**](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/initialize/initSingleDS.html):

```
sudo service cassandra stop
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/*
sudo vi /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml, setup the proper parameters
sudo service cassandra start
nodetool status
```

For some good cluster node setups, I found [this blog post](http://blog.powerupcloud.com/2016/01/10/install-and-configure-a-3-node-cassandra-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04/) to be very useful.

Comment: This helped me reset the cluster name so that I could follow https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/205289825-Change-Cluster-Name-

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 17):

I had same issue with Datastax4.7 enterprise edition. I resolved it with above instructions:

Change the cluster name back to "test Cluster"

start the cluster:

```
cqlsh> UPDATE system.local SET cluster_name = 'Cassendra Cluster' where key='local';
cqlsh> exit;
$ nodetool flush system
```

Stop the cluster:

```
$sudo service dse stop;sudo service datastax-agent stop
```

Edit the file:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
cluster_name: 'Cassendra Cluster'
```

Start the cluster:

```
$sudo service dse start;sudo service datastax-agent start
```

Check Installation log:

```
 $ cat /var/log/cassandra/output.log
```

Answer (score 9):

For Cassandra 3.0.5, I tired the answer by [Lyuben Todorov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22007669/3338779) but it was missing a key part:

```
bash $ ./nodetool flush
```

should be:

```
bash $ ./nodetool flush system
```

as in [here](https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/205289825-Change-Cluster-Name-)

Answer (score 3):

For Cassandra 3.7 you should replace the `./nodetool flush` with `./nodetool flush system`. Otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

If `cassandra` is not running, you can wipe the data folder.

```
rm -rf /usr/lib/cassandra/data/*
```

This will clear the system tables which had the wrong cluster name. \
When your restart `cassandra` with the correct cluster name in your `cassandra.yaml` everything will be regenerated and you should be good.

Comment: Deleting all of your data does fix the problem, but I am not sure this is the best thing to advise people.

Comment: I think it's unfair to downvote this answer. Early in the deployment process, flushing the data might be much easier than having to bring back up the cluster on it's previous name just to change it via cqlsh.

Answer (score 0):

For Bitnami certified Cassandra - 3.11.5

Here's the solution that worked for me:

1. Stop the Cassandra service

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh stop cassandra
```

2. Remove the system data

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/bitnami/cassandra/data/data/system/*
```

3. Start the Cassandra Service

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start cassandra
```