# Changing Cluster Name in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, rename

I have a cluster with 2 machines (centos7 and cassandra 3.4), 192.168.0.175 and 192.168.0.174. The seed is the 192.168.0.175.

I simply want to change the cluster name. Peace of cake should be.

I did on each cluster :

- `update system.local set cluster_name = 'America2' where key='local';`
- i did the nodetool flush
- i updated the cassandra.yaml with the new name
- restarted cassandra.

When i cqlsh any if describes me as connected to new cluster_name America2

When i run nodetool describecluster it shows the old cluster name America

If i stop cassandra on both machines and i try to restart them i find in logs the good old error :

`org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Saved cluster name America != configured name America2`

So....what am i doing wrong!?

Comment: I think you might need to decomission the nodes, stop them then, change the cluster name in the yaml then restart

Comment: I think you were not far from the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006887/cassandra-saved-cluster-name-test-cluster-configured-name

Comment: From what i feel is that the ```update of the system.local``` is not doing the job. From what i understand, when Cassie fires up checks both the cassandra.yaml & the system.local. IF the name checks in both places, all should come up without any problems. So, about cassandra.yaml i am sure...not sure if i make the change to system.local persistent.

Comment: did you stop cassandra before making the change in the yaml?

Comment: For one node cluster all the steps from above are working just fine. Testing more to figure out how to do it in a multi-node cluster

Comment: Did you restart the nodes separatly?

Comment: After some tests, did both down, both up and also one down, one up and viceversa and repaired after all ( i don`t really know if this step is neccessary - repair ) because i considered they might miss some while one is down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

before changing cluster name

1. delete node from cluster ring

   nodetool decommission
2. stop node and change cluster name in cassandra.yaml
3. clean node

   sudo rm -rf  /var/lib/cassandra/*  /var/log/cassandra/*
4. start cassandra node

More information you can find at [academy.datastax.com](https://academy.datastax.com/courses/ds210-datastax-enterprise-operations-and-performance-tuning/managing-cassandra-add-remove)

Comment: Yet the cluster is fresh, but considering production and you have some data, if i follow step 3 i might loose some!?

Comment: decommission is instrument how to be sure that you don't loose any data

Answer (score 2):

Ok guys, what i did :

cqlsh with each machine and :

`update system.local set cluster_name = 'canada' where key='local' ;`
then

`$ nodetool flush -- system`

then i stoped the service on both machines.

modified the cassandra.yaml with new cluster name canada.

started back the machines, they were working with new cluster name.

It is possible to do those steps without stoping all machines in the cluster, taking them out one by one( i think a repair on each node might be neccessary after ). Consider changing the seeds first.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really possible. I had the same problem. I solved this in a really dirty way. I wrote a script where i got all my column family data. Simply: A backup. Then i done this on each node: i stopped cassandra, i dropped all cassandras data, cache etc. (You can also reinstall cassandra.) i created a new cluster imported my backup. And i done this for each node.

Comment: op uses flush, this means he doesn't care about loosing data no?

Comment: ok, not the same, my bad. but I saw this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006887/cassandra-saved-cluster-name-test-cluster-configured-name