# Setting Cassandra on server IP

Tags: configuration, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, nosql

I'm trying to switch Cassandra from localhost to server IP where cassandra has been installed. 
In Cassandras config file:

```
cassandra.yaml
```

, I changed listen_address to my IP, also on seed and on rps_address. 
Beyond on picture you can see that also I have changed name of Cluster to

```
First Cluster
```

[image]

But when i start CQLSH I got:

[image]

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing. Changing the cluster name isn't that easy - see this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22006887/cassandra-saved-cluster-name-test-cluster-configured-name)

Comment: I'm intersted in chaning  IP, cluster is just an example..

Comment: ah, your image of the yaml file doesn't show the new IP address, sorry I missed it.

Comment: Did you restart the node after changing the settings ? And what command did you use to start cqlsh ? Did you try to run cqlsh from another node, using the new IP address ?

Comment: Yes, and I was starting the node with sh ~/cassandra/bin/cqlsh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If someone comes to this post and still don't know what the actually fu** is not working, here is the answer.

Listen address in cassandra always must stay on **localhost** but always. How to change the address than? 
Go in

```
cassandra.yaml
```

,and change:

```
rpc_address = your_server_IP ( it's on localhost)
rpc_start = true ( he is on false)
```

When you are trying to access cassandra in shell than type it like this:

```
sh ~cassandra/bin/cqlsh your_server_IP_which_you_set_as_RPC_ADDR
```

Something like:

```
sh ~cassandra/bin/cqlsh 10.12.123.123
```